# I am facing issue while trying to update "Java" in "windows 8.1" OS

Tags: java, installation, windows-8.1

java update failed

When i tried to update java getting an error mentioned below. Anyone can help me to resolve this issue

Error : Download failed:
from=http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/GetFile/1.8.0_65-b17/windows-i586/au.msi,to=C:\Users\dinesh\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\java\jre1.8.0_65\au.msi

Comment: 1) I don't see an image. Or link to an image. 2) I think maybe you should ask on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Comment: i tried to upload image but unable to do so .. sry

Comment: never mind, I still think you should look on superuser.com for a solution to your problem

Comment: i mentioned error .. pls look up tat

Answer (score 3):

Try to use "windows Offline" installation instead of "windows onLine" installation.
https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
open the link above and select Offline installation.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy issue?

It sounds to me as if it can't find the installer. What happens if you try loading the MSI linked in the error message using a web browser?

Comment: i am not aware about msi, would you pls give me solution

Comment: Try downloading this file directly:

http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/GetFile/1.8.0_65-b17/windows-i586/au.msi

You probably would be able to run it then. The issue is either:

* A proxy issue
* A permissions issue under Windows

tt's not a source code issue, so it's a little out of place here - as mentioned in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this error message on Win7 SP1 x64 for several weeks, since 2015-11-20 (when I made a screenshot of the message) until yesterday.

Today (2016-02-05) the installer finished successfully. I wasn't messing anything about Java, network settings nor temporary files.
Therefore my guess is that Oracle has made some fix, please retry now.